# How Can You Get Thumbnails for Jekyll Posts When the Post Has No Images?

Tags: jekyll

If I'm using Jekyll to build a blog and I want to share the link to posts. I'd like to have a preview thumbnail for the posts, however, the post itself has no images on it, and I'd like to keep it that way. Any ideas on how do that?

Comment: It's not Jekyll specific, but you need to use Open Graph Metadata (http://ogp.me/) to provide this to work. Also, http://vrepin.org/vr/JekyllMeta/#open-graph-metadata might be helpful to start – the author has link to example source code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found the solution I needed.

Following the [Open Graph Protocol](http://ogp.me/), if a post has a thumbnail image available for sharing via Facebook, Twitter, etc., you can specify your `<head>` open graph metadata like this.

```
{% if page.image %}
  <meta property="og:image" content="path/to/post/image.jpg">
{% else %}
  <meta property="og:image" content="path/to/page/image.jpg">
{% endif %}
```

If the *post* doesn't have a specified image it will use the image specified for the *page*. Then add the following to the post's [front matter](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/frontmatter/):

```
---
image: path/to/post/image.jpg
---
```

Answer (score 8):

You could define a `thumbnail` attribute in each post's front matter, then use that when you create the page containing links to your posts.

Here is an example blog post:

```
---
layout: default
thumbnail: "/path/to/the/thumbnail.png"
---
This is a blog post!
```

And then in your blog's `index.html` page, you'd do something like this:

```
{% for post in site.categories.blog %}
    <div>
        <a href="{{ post.url }}" ><img src="{{ post.thumbnail }}" />
        <a href="{{ post.url }}" >{{ post.title }}</a>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks, Kevin. That solution seems to add the thumbnail to the page and display it. I'm not looking to display it on the page but have a thumbnail show when the link is to the page is shared.

Comment: @MattSmith Maybe I misunderstood what you were going for. I thought you wanted your blog posts to not contain images, but still use thumbnails when you created links to them (like on a listing of all your blog posts). If you're talking about sharing this to facebook or something, that's a different thing. Although you could use the thumbnail frontmatter variable to set the opengraph metadata!

Comment: Thanks for following up Kevin. Yes, I want to have no pics on my blog post but have a thumbnail available when sharing to Facebook or Twitter or something else so it displays with the link. I'll look into using the frontmatter for that.